# C++ friend class with same name in different namespaces

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, c++-cli, friend

I have two classes with the same name in different namespaces. I cannot modify the names of the classes.
I want to add a method to one of the class, but I'm not allowed to add this as a public method. The other class is written in C++/CLI as ref class and needs access to this method.
I tried to use friend class but I have no idea how I should use it.

dll in standard c++:

```
namespace X
{
    class A
    {
        protected:
        __declspec(dllexport) void method();
    }
}
```

application in C++/CLI

```
namespace Y
{
    ref class A
    {
        void someMethod()
        {
            X::A otherClass;
            otherClass.method();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried the following:
friend class Y::A; // compiler error C2653: Y is not a class or namespace name

when I declare the namespace Y I get the error C2039: 'A' : is not a member of 'Y'

I cannot add a forward declaration of class A in namespace Y because class A is compiled with standard C++ and in a forward declaration I have to declare it as ref class.

Compiler: Visual Studio 2008

Does anybody have an idea?

Thank you

**Solution (thanks to Sorayuki):**

```
#ifdef __cplusplus_cli
    #define CLI_REF_CLASS ref class
#else
    #define CLI_REF_CLASS class
#endif

namespace Y { CLI_REF_CLASS A; }

namespace X
{
    class A
    {
        protected:
        friend CLI_REF_CLASS Y::A;
        __declspec(dllexport) void method();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this kind of trick is allowed.

but maybe you would like to have a look on this kind of "hacking":

in c++/cli

```
namespace Y
{
    class HackA : public X::A {
        public:
        void CallMethod() { method(); }
    };
    ref class A
    {
        void someMethod()
        {
            X::A otherClass;
            assert(sizeof(HackA) == (X::A));
            HackA* p = (HackA*) &otherClass;
            p->CallMethod();
        }
    };
};
```

**edit:**

I have tested that this could pass the compiling

```
namespace Y { ref class A; };

namespace X
{
    class A
    {
        friend ref class Y::A;
        protected:
        __declspec(dllexport) void method();
    };
};

namespace Y
{
    ref class A
    {
        void someMethod()
        {
            X::A otherClass;
            otherClass.method();
        }
    };
};
```

maybe you just need to copy the header file of X::A and edit the copy by adding a declare (not define) Y::A before namespace X. and include the "copy" instead.

Comment: I think this works but this is not a nice piece of code. I have to use this kind of hack if there is no different way but I don't know whether I'm allowed to use it.

Comment: Thank you but this does not compile with a standard C++ compiler. The dll does not use .NET. I've talked to my customer: I can use your first answer.

Comment: I know. So I suggest you to make a copy of that .h then modify it, or that dll will not compile. By the way, you may define a macro MYREF or something, when compiled with other compiler it's defined as nothing and when compiled with .net it's defined as "ref".